# Using r+ mode to read and write into the same file

Tags: python, file, csv, io

I have a script that successfully removes a column from a csv file. Currently it does this by creating a new file. I want it to write to the original file rather than create a new one.
I’ve tried this by using the r+ mode for open but it’s not working how I want. See notes below. I think r+ mode is the one I need but I’m struggling to find working examples to learn from.

my code:

```
    import csv

    in_file = "Path to Source"
    out_file = "Path to Result"

    with open(in_file, 'r', newline='') as inf, \
        open(out_file, 'w', newline='') as outf:
     reader = csv.reader(inf)
     writer = csv.writer(outf)

     for r in reader:
         writer.writerow((r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6]))
```

attempt using `r+` mode:

```
with open(in_file, 'r+', newline='') as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(inf)

    for r in reader:
        writer.writerow((r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6]))
```

This fails with the error `list index out of range`

Comment: from what I see, as the reader reads, the writer writes. Files have a 'cursor', i.e. a current position upon which they are read from/written to. So the writer is overwriting the next row after the one the reader has just read. Why not create a new file and then rename it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, as the reader reads, the writer writes. On the same file.

Files have a 'cursor', i.e. a current position upon which they are read from/written to.

So the writer is overwriting the next row in the file after the one the reader has just read, with catastrophic consequences on the following readings.

I think the first approach is the best one: create a new file and then rename it (the original input file is deleted automatically)

```
import csv, os
in_file = "Path to Source"
out_file = "Path to Result"

with open(in_file, 'r', newline='') as inf, \
     open(out_file, 'w', newline='') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for r in reader:
        writer.writerow(r[:7])

os.rename(out_file, in_file)
```

Comment: Thanks Pynchia. I got an error cannot rename when file exist so inserted os.remove(in_file)  just before os.rename(out_file, in_file) and this now works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bassmann: Since you're using `newline=''`, I'm guessing you're using Python 3. If that's the case (and you're on 3.3 or higher), you can use [`os.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace), which has consistent replacing behavior on Linux and Windows (replacing existing files without a prompt). Avoids the race conditions involved with deleting, then renaming.